# Does the tiny helicopter drone black hornet use a swash plate?

Tags: design, helicopters, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

[image]

I've been looking over some pictures of the drone above but I'm not sure if it uses a swash plate or not. I understand there are some *freely hinged rotor* concepts known to work at this scale but I'm not really sure about this one.

Comment: Based on slide 13 of this 2014 [PowerPoint presentation](https://www.ntnu.no/documents/10355/1262992082/Prox+Dynamics+-+Kybernetisk+fagdag+071114.pdf/b8a66094-2838-4e62-bb9c-f61975addf51), it looks like it does.

Comment: @sempaiscuba that's the best answer I've seen to this question, perhaps consider making an answer based on it and get some rep in the process ;)

Answer (score 3):

No. The Flir Black Hornet Nano UAV does not have a swashplate.  The rotor blade pitch is controlled directly by servos at each blade root. The servos are held by a structure that rotates around the rotor mast.  If you zoom in, [this picture](https://images.app.goo.gl/VQLetjgYA8k8pcUBA) shows the two “button” servos clamped in the support structure.
[image: Drone side view]

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any servos directly on the blade roots. Perhaps I'm missing something. Could you provide a link or source of where you found this information?

Comment: @Jim what are those metallic beads near the servos for?

Comment: The metallic beads are most likely weights. Rotor blades need their centre of gravity to be quite far forward to reduce control loads and prevent flutter. This way, if a gust of wind causes the blade to flap up, the weight will pitch it back down. Larger helicopters can have blades that are hollow at the back.

Answer (score 1):

Based on slide 13 of this [2014 PowerPoint presentation](https://www.ntnu.no/documents/10355/1262992082/Prox+Dynamics+-+Kybernetisk+fagdag+071114.pdf/b8a66094-2838-4e62-bb9c-f61975addf51), it looks like the *PD-100 Black Hornet* does indeed incorporate a swash plate.

[image: Image of slide 13]

---

Now, a caveat here is that slide appears at the end of the section describing the development of the Hornet series of drones.  **It does not state explicitly that all the systems shown are present in the Hornet 4 / PD-100 Black Hornet**.

---

However, comparing what we can see of the drive mechanisms in [this video](https://www.military.com/video/military-intelligence/surveillance/meet-the-black-hornet-specops-nano-uav/4269138650001), for example at 40s:

[image: Image of Black Hornet rotor]

and the low-res images of earlier models in the Hornet series shown in slide 10 of the presentation cited above,

[image: Hornet series of drones]

they do all look to be closely related to the [rotor assembly mechanism](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/53/15/0f/b706a3abbd9c02/EP2499045B1.pdf) (European patent number EP 2 499 045 B1) patented in 2010 by *Petter Muren*, founder of *Prox Dynamics*.  That rotor assembly includes a rotating swash plate.

---

Prox Dynamics was the company that developed the *PD-100 Black Hornet*.  Prox Dynamics was subsequently acquired by *FLIR Systems* in 2016.